# Activity does not start until the screen is turned on

Tags: android, screen, wakelock, keyguard

My service starts an Activity like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, CallMonitor.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

this happens in CallMonitor.onCreate():

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```

On most devices, the activity (called up from service) wakes up the device, turns on the screen and is displayed.

But - for example - on Galaxy Tab 4, the activity **is only called if the screen is already switched on**.
If the screen is switched off and the service calls up the activity, it is displayed with a **delay** - It will be displayed **immediatly after turning the screen on**.

There is also a voice output in the activity. When the Galaxy S4 is switched off, it will not be played back - but immediatly after turning the screen on again.

Any suggestions?
I don't want to use WakeLock!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that's a device limitation and I don't know how you could work around that without using a WakeLock. We have a really old piece of code which you could modify to your needs which pretty much always worked for us:

```
public static void bringToFront() {
    try {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) MainActivity.getAppContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "ALARM");
        wl.acquire();
        KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) MainActivity.getAppContext().getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        lock.disableKeyguard();
        if (MainActivity.getAppActivity() != null) {
            MainActivity.getAppActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        }
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.w(TAG, "bringToFront Err: "+e.toString());
    }
}
```